# "add to cart" button works on localhost but not on cpanel (using sessions)

Tags: javascript, php, html, session, cookies

I have contacted godaddy and everything looks good on their end. This code works on my localhost when using xampp but not when uploaded on cpanel. MYSQL works. I am using sessions only to make the "add to cart" button work. When I click the button it refreshes but doesn't add anything to cart. Do I also have to use cookies? If I do then how can I add it to this code?

```
<?php 
session_start();
$connect = mysqli_connect( "localhost", "username", "pass", "");
if(isset($_POST["add_to_cart"]))
{
    if(isset($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]))
    {
        $item_array_id = array_column($_SESSION["shopping_cart"],   "item_id");
    if(!in_array($_GET["id"], $item_array_id))
    {
        $count = count($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]);
        $item_array = array(
            'item_id'           =>  $_GET["id"],
            'item_name'         =>  $_POST["hidden_name"],
            'item_price'        =>  $_POST["hidden_price"],
            'item_quantity'     =>  $_POST["quantity"]
        );
        $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$count] = $item_array;
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<script>alert("Item Already Added")</script>';
    }
}
else
{
    $item_array = array(
        'item_id'           =>  $_GET["id"],
        'item_name'         =>  $_POST["hidden_name"],
        'item_price'        =>  $_POST["hidden_price"],
        'item_quantity'     =>  $_POST["quantity"]
    );
    $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][0] = $item_array;
}
}
if(isset($_GET["action"]))
{
 if($_GET["action"] == "delete")
 {
    foreach($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $keys => $values)
    {
        if($values["item_id"] == $_GET["id"])
        {
            unset($_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$keys]);
            echo '<script>alert("Item Removed")</script>';
            echo '<script>window.location="mysqlcart.php"</script>';
        }
    }
}
}
?>

<?php
if(!empty($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]))
{
    $total = 0;         
        $return = [];                
    foreach($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $keys => $values)              {
?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $values["item_name"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $values["item_quantity"]; ?></td>
    <td>$ <?php echo $values["item_price"]; ?></td>
    <td>$ <?php echo number_format($values["item_quantity"] * $values["item_price"], 2);?></td>
    <td><a href="mysqlcart.php?action=delete&id=<?php echo $values["item_id"]; ?>"><span class="text-danger">Remove</span></a></td>
    </tr>
<?php
    $total = $total + ($values["item_quantity"] * $values["item_price"]); 
    $return[] = $values["item_quantity"];   
    $return[] = $values["item_name"];               
    }
?>
<?php
}
?>

<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_product.tbl_product ORDER BY id ASC";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
?>
<form method="post" action="mysqlcart.php?action=add&id=<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>">          
    <input type="text" name="quantity" value="1" class="form-control" />
    <input type="hidden" name="hidden_name" value="<?php echo $row["name"]; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="hidden_price" value="<?php echo $row["price"]; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" name="add_to_cart" style="margin-top:5px;" class="btn btn-success" value="Add to Cart" />
            </form>
        <?php
                }
            }
        ?>
```

Comment: side note, price should not be posted from your form any one could change that

Comment: try do a print_r($_SESSION) and see whats the output

Comment: Can you post the link? also take note of IdontDownVote's comment **NEVER take important values like price from your front-end** people could get away with $1000 worth of item  by just paying $1.ALWAYS use the item's ID to query your DB the price of that item and then only use it.

Comment: Used <?php
session_start();
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_SESSION);
echo "</pre>";
?>  All it shows is Array().   [link]  (https://www.royaspa.com/mysqlcart)